# Do I have to use getters and setters for a following class?

Tags: vba

So, I need a Class, that has a structure like this:

```
Obj
    .Name
        .value as string
        .tag as string
    .Id
        .value as string
        .tag as string
```

With those `value` and `tag` member variables being accesible from the outside. So I tried to write a class using Types.

```
'make a "RefPairType" Type for value/tag pair 
Public Type RefPairType
    value As String
    tag as String
End Type

'Make member vars of the class based on RefPairType 
Private Name As RefPairType
Private Id As RefPairType
```

Obviously, since those members are private I cannot interact with them on the module level. Code on the module level:

```
Private Sub Document_New()
    'create an exemplar of aforementioned Class called "Class1"
    Dim client As New Class1

    'try to assign value to the member:
    client.Name.value = "foo"
    'COMPILE ERROR: method or data member not found
End Sub
```

And if I make those Types or member variables public I get errors:

```
'Cannot define a public user-defined type within an object module
```

or

```
'constants, ... user-defined types not allowed as public members of object modules
```

Does that mean I have to make getters/setters for every member variable of the class? What if my class is 10 times bigger? How do I even make getters and setters for a nested member like object.name.tag?

Comment: Using Types is a major pain - you'd be better off making your Type a Class instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Type` is not a class, or an object. It's very little more than a chunk of memory with a specific layout. If you have something you can have an instance of, that you can `New` up, then you don't want a `Type`, but a class module. User-defined types have many restrictions that make them rather hard to work with, at least from an OOP perspective.

In this case you want a `ValueTagPair` or something, might look like this - note how a `Private Type` can be still be used to hold the instance state under a single private field (`this`):

```
Option Explicit
Private Type TPair
    Value As String 
    Tag As String
End Type
Private this As TPair

Public Property Get Value() As String
    Value = this.Value
End Property

Public Property Let Value(ByVal rhs As String)
    this.Value = rhs
End Property

Public Property Get Tag() As String
    Tag = this.Tag
End Property

Public Property Let Tag(ByVal rhs As String)
    this.Tag = rhs
End Property
```

Now you can declare any variable `As ValueTagPair`, and use it as such - including as the return type of a `Property` member on another class.

```
Option Explicit
Private Type TSomething
    Name As ValueTagPair
    Id As ValueTagPair
End Type
Private this As TSomething

Public Property Get Name() As ValueTagPair
    Set Name = this.Name
End Property

Public Property Get Id() As ValueTagPair
    Set Id = this.Id
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set this.Name = New ValueTagPair
    Set this.Id = New ValueTagPair
End Sub
```

Now assuming that's a `Something` class, we can now do this:

```
Dim thing As Something
Set thing = New Something
thing.Name.Tag = "name-tag"
thing.Name.Value = "name-value"
thing.Id.Tag = "id-tag"
thing.Id.Value = "id-value"
```

If you need to be able to do `Set thing.Name = New ValueTagPair`, then you'll have to expose a `Public Property Set` member for the `Name` property.

> *Does that mean I have to make getters/setters for every member variable of the class?*

Yes. The public members of a class define that class' interface, and an interface determines how an object can be used. If `Class1.Name` isn't exposed on the interface of `Class1`, then it doesn't exist; early-bound usage won't compile, and late-bound member calls (i.e. calls made against `Object` or `Variant`) will blow up at run-time with error 438.

> *What if my class is 10 times bigger?*

Then it likely has too many responsibilities. Objects with a clear and well-defined purpose don't typically do 20 things.

Comment: I've seen people using `this` before, but didn't find it as a keyword in VBA. Is it just a coincidence?

Comment: It's an instance variable. You could name it `foo` or `elephant` if you wanted.

Comment: `Me` is the VBA equivalent of other languages' `this`